# Image path and remove attribute not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a ReactJs app and I'm new in the complete React theme, right now I'm facing two problems.

The first one is that I cannot read the path of an image, bellow is my folder structure.

[image]

I want to call the image from the Login.jsx file, I tried.

```
<Image src = {"../assets/images/SiteLogo.png"} fluid />
```

But it does not seem to work

The other problem I'm experiencing is with react-particle-js, when I tried to remove the width and height attribute the canvas have, nothing happens.

I remove the style properties, but I cannot remove the attributes.

Here is my code:

```
let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.style.removeProperty("width");
canvas.style.removeProperty("height");
canvas.removeAttribute("width");
canvas.removeAttribute("height");
```

Answer (score 0):

**First problem:**

You can't refer to paths on the local filesystem from a served page, you need to actually serve your assets over HTTP. If you are already doing this, please include the relevant code.

**Second problem:**

Manually manipulated DOM generated by React is a big no-no (your changes will be overwritten when the component renders), you need to configure `react-particle-js` to not set those properties in the first place